# asp-for renders input field too big

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

Is there some data-annotation to adjust the physical size of an input field? This code renders input fields that are way too big:

```
<input asp-for="@item.Quantity" />
```

[image: with asp-for="@item.Quantity"]

It doesn't help to put `size="1"` in there either.

This code renders the field just like I want it to be, but I don't get the validation:

```
<input name="item.Quantity" id="item.Quantity" value="@item.Quantity" size="1" />
```

[image: with plain HTML]

I have tried `[MaxLength(3)]` and `[Range(0,99)]`, but it didn't help.

The viewmodel for cart items:

```
public class ViewModelShoppingCartItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(3)]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal LineSum => ProductPrice * Quantity;
}
```

Comment: The appearance and layout of your `<input>` element will be set by CSS, not ASP.NET. Use your browser's Inspector window to see how you can change the size of the input. I note that the `size=""` attribute is not specific, you should use the CSS `width` attribute to specify an actual width, for example.

Comment: I tried adding `class="col-xs-1"`. That indeed made the field small, but it messed up the design. Now the input field is rendered to the left of x (-)(+), and the space inside the `<td>` is not affected, it stays as big as if the input field was like before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarresing...

Just adding `style="width:50px;"` did it ...

Thanks anyway! :D

Comment: Don't do that. Understand the tools you're using. ASP.NET Core websites employ Bootstrap by default. So, either use Bootstrap, or replace it with something you prefer better. As far as Bootstrap goes, `col-xs-1` is not enough on it's own. You need a `row` element and potentially an overall `container`/`container-fluid` element. See Bootstrap documentation for more info.